# Error occurred while the connection of registration API by through PHP in android

Tags: java, php, android, json

I try to connect Login and Registration form through PHP API, But I get the error and I don't understand how its will be resolve. I check the solution regarding this error but I don't understand it. Thank you in advance!

Error :-

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Here is my code for Registration form (Login.java)

Login. java (This is the java file where for Registration)

```
public class Login extends Activity {
    EditText editname, editemail, editpassword, editmobile;
    Button btnRegister;
    private static final String TAG = "Login";
    private static final String URL_FOR_REGISTRATION = "http://codexpertise.com/codexpertise.com/apitest/signup.php";
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ImageButton btnfb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
        // Progress dialog
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        editname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editname);
        editemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editemail);
        editpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpassword);
        editmobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editmobile);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnfb = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnfb);




        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                submitForm();
            }

            private void submitForm() {
                registerUser(editname.getText().toString(),
                        editemail.getText().toString(),
                        editpassword.getText().toString(),
                        editmobile.getText().toString());

            }

            private void registerUser(final String name,  final String email, final String password,
                                      final String mobile) {
                // Tag used to cancel the request
                String cancel_req_tag = "register";

                progressDialog.setMessage("Adding you ...");
                showDialog();

                StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                        URL_FOR_REGISTRATION, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                        hideDialog();

                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                            if (!error) {
                                String user = jObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("name");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi " + user +", You are successfully Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                // Launch login activity
                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        Login.this,
                                        MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            } else {

                                String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        hideDialog();
                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        // Posting params to register url
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("name", name);
                        params.put("email", email);
                        params.put("password", password);
                        params.put("gender", mobile);
                        return params;
                    }
                };
                // Adding request to request queue
                AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(strReq, cancel_req_tag);
            }

            private void showDialog() {
                if (!progressDialog.isShowing())
                    progressDialog.show();
            }

            private void hideDialog() {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        });

        btnfb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

}
```

Here is the some image which i test it on postman

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCxB3.png)

Check this

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqdAa.png)

Comment: please provide your json response.

Comment: Share your response?If data is not valid json error will occur like this

Comment: Okay sir i share my response which i test it on postman

Comment: @KunalPitale your screen shot and both diffrent url **private static final String URL_FOR_REGISTRATION = "http://codexpertise.com/codexpertise.com/apitest/signup.php";**

Comment: post signup.php..

Comment: @KunalPitale add signup response here.

Comment: @Guruji i post it signup response here. Please check it

Comment: @KunalPitale your test with postman doesn't match with the code. In your code you use the request-parameter "name", "email", "password" and "gender" but with postman you use "type", "username" and "password"

Comment: @devpuh i rectify the request parameter in my java code

Comment: @KunalPitale At the moment your post is incomplete and has misleading information. Please add the response which you receive with your code and remove the images from the postman test, since you're using a different request. Also avoid to use images if they only contain text.

Comment: @devpuh I don't get any response from my code just get this error. and specially its targeted on this two lines 
                'StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                        URL_FOR_REGISTRATION, new Response.Listener<String>()' and JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);

Comment: @KunalPitale You actually get a response which also gets logged with `Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());`, but it's probably not what you expect.

Comment: will you provide me your mail id because i am not unable to chat here right now. So let we discuss on mail and shortout the problem.

Comment: @KunalPitale that's not how stackoverflow works, please edit your question, so that it contains all necessary information.

Comment: okay @devpuh but nothing is change in the code, i get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

your response not any `boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");` so you can read your response code and change your condition as your requirement..

```
 try 
    {
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
        String  respCode = jObj.getString("resp_code");
        //boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

        if (respCode.equals("200")) {
            String user = jObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("name");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi " + user +", You are successfully Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Launch login activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Login.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {

            String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @Kunal Pitale please check ans.

Comment: will u please provide me your mail id so i can discuss with you there